# How can I set up a caching DNS server on my Macintosh?

Tags: dns

With the DDOS attack on the Dyn DNS service last week, I lost a day of productivity.  Can I set up a DNS service on my MacPro laptop?

I envision it just caching the DNS info from the usual servers.  If they go down, it can use the reasonably current info stored locally, and I can keep working.

Is that possible?

Comment: You would be better off using a cloud-hosted linux instance and setting up something more reliable. Like BIND configured as a caching server. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04 Doing this on a Mac OS X client would be kludgy and unreliable. If you do want to go that route, I wouldn't go much further than just adding some common ones to /etc/hosts -- which is straightforward but not scalable at all. OS X Server has some capabilities to run a DNS Caching Server, but I suspect you're not running that.

Comment: Hmm.  I fear not being able to reach the cloud instance.  Wouldn't it have to pass through a DNS server, to find the IP for the cloud instance?  On Friday, the DNS servers were down.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation about how to set up a caching server.  I put the IP for OpenDNS in my list of DNS servers to check.  They were up Friday.  Maybe that will be enough.

Comment: True, with DNS servers there is that chick and egg situation. So they are usually referred to only by IP address. (Example, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are some easy to remember ones (Google's public servers))

Comment: Ah.  I get it.  Thanks.

Comment: Jameson, feel free to post your first comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.  Pull request, maybe.  :^D

Comment: much appreciated, Sir -- this should set me over 2000! Been looking forward to that for a while. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using a cloud-hosted linux instance and setting up something more reliable. Like BIND configured as a caching server. Here is some discussion of that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Doing this on a Mac OS X client would be kludgy and unreliable. If you do want to go that route, I wouldn't go much further than just adding some common ones to `/etc/hosts` -- which is straightforward to do, but not scalable at all.

OS X Server has some capabilities to run a DNS Caching Server, but I suspect you're not running that.